# Changing value of a global variable from the inside of function using input

Tags: javascript

I have a

```
var imgSrc = false;
dom.getElByTag('img')[0].onclick = function(){
  //set src of image
  changeBool(dom.getElByTag('img')[0]);
}

function changeBool(n){
    if(n.src ===="file/path"){
    imgSrc = true;
};

console.log(imgSrc);
```

So the problem is that imgSrc is only changed locally in changeBool so if I console.log imgSrc it will return false, regardless of where I put it (this is likely because the page has already loaded and decided that imgSrc is false before I set it to true with the onclick, and since javascript runs one line at a time it has run console.log(imgSrc) as false before I could even click the image.

So, I need to:

declare a boolean as false -> click an image, which sets boolean as true -> console.logging the boolean (and seeing true)

But what I am doing right now is:
declare a boolean as false -> console.logging the boolean (and seeing false {because it hasn't been set to true yet} - > clicking an image and setting the boolean to true.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @MoeChughtai You seem to have two different accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7392646/moe-chughtai and http://stackoverflow.com/users/7377678/moe-chughtai. Please request to merge your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/contact.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your logging statement inside the `changeBool` function like so:

```
var imgSet = false;
dom.getElByTag('img')[0].onclick = function(){
  //set src of image
  changeBool(dom.getElByTag('img')[0]);
}

function changeBool(n){
    if(n.src ===="file/path") imgSrc = true;
    console.log(imgSrc);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first line of code,

```
var imgSet = false;
```

Needs to be changed to

```
var imgSrc = false;
```